# Mysql Select where time difference between columns date

Tags: php, mysql, unix, unix-timestamp

How to query by selecting rows where time difference between columns date greater than X days

```
ID            Date1                        Date2
1             2017-02-01T00:00:00          2017-02-15T00:00:00
```

Note: Time stored in  2017-02-15T00:00:00 format.

I tried this

```
WHERE TIMEDIFF(DAY, Date1, Date2) > 1
```

Comment: Is `Date2` always after `Date1`?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `TIMEDIFF()` takes a unit argument before the two times?

Comment: @Barmar yes, Date2 always after Date1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DATEDIFF()

```
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(date1, date2)) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As @uran mentioned above you could use `DATEDIFF`:

```
WHERE (DATEDIFF(date1, date2) AS days) > 1;
```

Hope this  [Ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) helps you!

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(Date1,Date2) > 1
```